# Demuxing values from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

A device sends an array of multiplexed error codes. You can think of the multiplexed error codes as some sort of FIFO ring buffer that can have a variable length depending on the number of simultaneously active error code. I wish to demultiplex the error codes into individual boolean arrays.

I'm looking for an efficient way (i.e. removing the for loop) to implement the following code:

```py
import numpy as np

def get_error_vector(error_mux_vector, error_id, period):
    index = np.where(error_mux_vector == error_id)[0]

    error_vector = np.zeros(np.size(error_mux_vector))

    for i in range(0, np.size(index) - 1):
        if (index[i + 1] - index[i]) <= 1 / period:
            error_vector[index[i]:index[i + 1] + 1] = 1

    return error_vector
```

Here are mock values to illustrate the problem. 0 means no error; 1, 2, and 3 are error codes. We assume the error signal has a frequency of 5 Hz (period of 0.2s) :

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

error_signal = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,1,2,3,2,3,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,2,2])

error_vector_1 = get_error_vector(error_signal, 1, 0.2)
error_vector_2 = get_error_vector(error_signal, 2, 0.2)
error_vector_3 = get_error_vector(error_signal, 3, 0.2)

plt.plot(error_signal)
plt.plot(error_vector_1)
plt.plot(error_vector_2)
plt.plot(error_vector_3)
plt.legend(['array', 'error 1', 'error 2', 'error 3'])
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot output]

The actual device data can have from 50k to 10M points, with around 100 possible error codes. This means that a for loop is really inefficient for the use case. I would like to improve this code but I haven't found an efficient solution so far.

Comment: Is using pandas allowed? You effectively want to perform a group operation which is easier to do in pandas in most cases.

Comment: I'd rather stay in numpy if possible. Do you have an insight on how to do this with pandas groupby? I'm not sure I'm seeing it. It is important to keep error vectors (arrays) as the output because they are used to slice data in for processing.

Comment: I think there is a bug in your snippet. In the `else` clause it looks as if you meant `error_vector[index[i]]`. Actually, I would drop the else clause altogether, since all it does is remove points you've added before.

Comment: You are right about the `else` clause. It reassigns `0` to an array position that is already `0`. I edited my snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a vectorized approach that creates all vectors in one go. It comes in two flavors. On my random test case the second is faster but that may depend on the exact stats of your signal.

```
import numpy as np

# dense strat
def demultiplex(signal,maxdist):
    n = signal.max()
    aux = np.zeros((n,len(signal)+1),np.int16)
    nz = signal.nonzero()[0]
    signal = signal[nz]
    idx = signal.argsort(kind="stable")
    valid = ((nz[idx[1:]]<=nz[idx[:-1]]+maxdist)&
             (signal[idx[1:]]==signal[idx[:-1]])).nonzero()[0]
    aux[signal[idx[valid]]-1,nz[idx[valid]]] = 1
    aux[signal[idx[valid+1]]-1,nz[idx[valid+1]]+1] -= 1
    out = (aux[:,:-1].cumsum(1) > 0).view(np.int8)
    return out

# sparse strat
def demultiplex2(signal,maxdist):
    n = signal.max()
    m = signal.size
    nz = signal.nonzero()[0]
    signal = signal[nz]
    idx = signal.argsort(kind="stable")
    delta = nz[idx[1:]] - nz[idx[:-1]]
    valid = ((delta<=maxdist)&(signal[idx[1:]]==signal[idx[:-1]])).nonzero()[0]
    delta = delta[valid]
    nz = nz[idx[valid]]
    nz[1:] -= nz[:-1] + delta[:-1]
    offsets = (delta+1).cumsum()
    x = np.ones(offsets[-1],int)
    x[0] = nz[0]
    x[offsets[:-1]] = nz[1:]
    out = np.zeros((n,m),np.uint8)
    out[(signal[idx[valid]]-1).repeat(delta+1),x.cumsum()] = 1
    return out

# OP
def get_error_vector(error_mux_vector, error_id, period):
    index = np.where(error_mux_vector == error_id)[0]
    error_vector = np.zeros(np.size(error_mux_vector),np.int8)
    for i in range(0, np.size(index) - 1):
        if (index[i + 1] - index[i]) <= 1 / period:
            error_vector[index[i]:index[i + 1] + 1] = 1
    return error_vector


#error_signal = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,1,2,3,2,3,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,2,2])
error_signal = np.random.randint(0,101,1000000)

import time

t=[]
t.append(time.time())
error_vector_1 = get_error_vector(error_signal, 1, 0.02)
error_vector_2 = get_error_vector(error_signal, 2, 0.02)
error_vector_3 = get_error_vector(error_signal, 3, 0.02)
t.append(time.time())
sol = demultiplex(error_signal,50)
t.append(time.time())
sol2 = demultiplex2(error_signal,50)
t.append(time.time())
print("time per error id [OP, pp, pp2]",np.diff(t)/(3,100,100))
print("results equal",end=" ")
print((error_vector_1==sol[0]).all(),end=" ")
print((error_vector_2==sol[1]).all(),end=" ")
print((error_vector_3==sol[2]).all(),end=" ")
print((error_vector_1==sol2[0]).all(),end=" ")
print((error_vector_2==sol2[1]).all(),end=" ")
print((error_vector_3==sol2[2]).all())
```

Sample run:

```
time per error id [OP, pp, pp2] [0.02730425 0.00912964 0.00440736]
results equal True True True True True True
```

BIt of explanation:

- we argsort signal to easily identify those error codes which are followed by themselves in close enough time.
- we arrange the error vectors in a stack so points that should be set can be addressed by coordinate signal[t],t
- to set stretches of time points we set the first to 1 and the one after the last to -1 and form the cumsum - to remedy overlapping stretches we check >0 and cast the resulting boolean to int

Comment: That does it exactly, very nice! Can you elaborate a little on :
`aux[signal[idx[valid]]-1,nz[idx[valid]]] = 1`
`aux[signal[idx[valid+1]]-1,nz[idx[valid+1]]+1] -= 1`
`out = (aux[:,:-1].cumsum(1) > 0).view(np.int8)` ?

I'm not sure I get the intent.